# jQuery Show image preview from input text box

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to show image preview using bootstrap popover from input box value with `type="text"` like this :

[image]

HTML :

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" value="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/b64518ca2a465c3ef67299a39758c383?s=100&r=g&d=mm">
```

how do can i show preview in input hover?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample codes:

```
$(function () {
    $("#example")
        .popover({ title: 'Twitter Bootstrap Popover', content: "It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" })
        .blur(function () {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        });
});
```